# Geometric difference of regions with internal boundaries with boost geometry

Tags: boost, geometry, boost-geometry

I'd like to take the geometric difference of two geometric objects with **Boost Geometry**. The first geometry is:

[image]

I always have line segments making up the geometry. I have the coordinates and the segments:

```
{{-1., -1.}, {1., -1.}, {1., 1.}, {-1., 1.}, {0.6, -1}, {0.6,1.}};
{Line[{{1, 5}, {5, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 6}, {6, 4}, {4, 1}}], Line[{{5, 6}}]};
```

were each index in the lines refers to a coordinates. Either of the geometries can have internal boundaries (and holes).

The second geometry:

[image]

And I am expecting to obtain this:

[image]

I have started with *polygon* but I do not understand how I could include the interior boundary of the first geometric object. While one can have interior holes I am missing how to have a 'degenerated' polygon like a line. Also it's not clear to me which of the two polygons then would be the outer polygon. Then I thought about *line*, but there I can not add the internal segment. Can Boost Geometry be used find geometric Boolean operations for geometries with internal boundaries and it so, how would I do that?

The code for the polygon approach that misses the internal boundary; commented out is the line type approach; again with out the internal boundary in first geometric object.

```
#include <iostream>                                                             
#include <fstream>                                                              
#include <list>                                                                 

#include <boost/geometry.hpp>                                                   
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>                               
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>                                

#include <boost/foreach.hpp>                                                    

int main()                                                                      
{                                                                               
    typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> point_type;            
    typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<point_type > polygon;               
    //typedef boost::geometry::model::linestring<point_type > line;             

    polygon p1, p2;                                                             
    //line l1, l2;                                                              

    boost::geometry::read_wkt(                                                  
        "POLYGON((-1 -1, 0.6 -1, 1 -1, 1 1, 0.6 1, -1 1))", p1);                

    boost::geometry::read_wkt(                                                  
        "POLYGON((-0.5 -0.5, 2 -0.5, 2 0.5, -0.5 0.5))", p2);                   

    /*                                                                          
    boost::geometry::read_wkt(                                                  
        "LINESTRING(-1 -1, 0.6 -1, 1 -1, 1 1, 0.6 1, -1 1)", l1);               

    boost::geometry::read_wkt(                                                  
        "LINESTRING(-0.5 -0.5, 2 -0.5, 2 0.5, -0.5 0.5)", l2);                  
    */                                                                          

    std::list<polygon> output;                                                  
    boost::geometry::difference(p2, p1, output);                                

    //std::list<line> loutput;                                                  
    //boost::geometry::difference(l2, l1, loutput);                             

    std::ofstream svg("my_map.svg");                                            
    boost::geometry::svg_mapper<point_type> mapper(svg, 400, 400);              

    int i = 0;                                                                  
    BOOST_FOREACH(polygon const& p, output)                                     
    {                                                                           
        mapper.add(p);                                                          
        mapper.map(p, "fill-opacity:0.3;fill:rgb(51,151,53);stroke:rgb(51,151,53);stroke-width:2");  
    }                                                                           

    /*                                                                          
    int i = 0;                                                                  
    BOOST_FOREACH(line const& l, loutput)                                       
    {                                                                           
        mapper.add(l);                                                          
        mapper.map(l, "opacity:0.4;fill:none;stroke:rgb(212,0,0);stroke-width:5");
    }                                                                           
    */                                                                          

    return 0;                                                                   
}
```

Comment: You could try to split the first geometry into two touching rectangles. The interior line would then actually be two coinciding sides. Or you could try to model the interior line as a spike running into the rectangle e.g. from the bottom to the top and immediately back again (a degenerated inwards dent), i.e. `POLYGON((-1 -1, 0.6 -1, 0.6 1, 0.6 -1, 1 -1, 1 1, -1 1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner line can be modeled as a spike from e.g. the bottom. This approximation works:

```
boost::geometry::read_wkt(
    "POLYGON((-1 -1, 0.6 -1, 0.6 1, 0.60000000000001 -1, 1 -1, 1 1, -1 1))", p1);
```

Two polygons are created: the small lower right almost-rectangle `(0.60000000000001 -1, 1 -1, 1 -0.5, 0.6 -0.5)` is not connected to the rest.

This exact list of points

```
boost::geometry::read_wkt(
    "POLYGON((-1 -1, 0.6 -1, 0.6 1, 0.6 -1, 1 -1, 1 1, -1 1))", p1);
```

raises an exception because of a self intersection. When jumping over the check for self intersection we get a result, but it is incomplete (only the bigger of the two above polygons is computed).

What would, of course, also work, is splitting the polygon `p1` into two rectangles:

```
boost::geometry::read_wkt(
    "POLYGON((-1 -1, 0.6 -1, 0.6 1, -1 1))", p11);
boost::geometry::read_wkt(
    "POLYGON((0.6 -1, 1 -1, 1 1, 0.6 1))", p12);
```

Then computing each difference with `p2` and joining the results gives the exact expected answer (as three separate rectangles).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your time. Your second suggestion comes across as the more viable one. Then, however, I would have to find a way to convert the original line segment representation I have (see update of question) into a list of polygons. I do not immediately see how to do that, in fact it is quite difficult to do so. From you answer I believe that boost may not be the right tool for what I want to do. I'll leave this open for a bit longer to see if someone else can come up with a way to do this. Thanks again!

Comment: Your specification is still not clear: do you always have input like `{polygon, lines}`? Do the single lines only appear in the first geometry? If single lines can also appear in the second geometry, you would have to define what difference means in this context? Shall single lines in the second geometry be ignored for computing the difference? Anyway, the output could then be of the form `{polygons, lines}`. The only thing missing would then be an algorithm for computing `line - polygon`.

Comment: Either geometry can have internal segments (and holes) and the geometry is made up of line segements. RegionDifference(p1, p2) means all of p2 (internal boundaries included) are subtracted from p1. Since p2 will not be part of the result of the difference there is nothing to worry about. For region holes that is a different story but not part of the question. I appreciate your help very much, but I have come to the conclusion that boost geometry is not going to cut it for me.